# Code Runner not showing the correct output in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am having trouble running some code using VS Code's Code Runner, as it does not appear in color and displays old data. Even after clearing the output, the same result occurs when I run the code again. Interestingly, the code works correctly using the interactive panel on the right. I have checked the extension settings, but everything appears to be in order. Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Code Output Issue:

[image: Code Output Issue]

Code Runner Extension Settings:

[image: Code Runner Extension Settings]

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall the extension but no luck.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Your test.py file tab shows a white dot. It seems changes to the file have not been saved yet. I'm guessing you changed the range to `0,12,2`, but since the file hasn't been saved yet, code runner doesn't see that change yet.

Comment: As for "*as it does not appear in color*", not really sure what you mean here, but you will have to actually write code to produce output with color. You might have seen some interactive shells that colorize your outputs, but that's not the case with Code Runner, which outputs exactly what code was written.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I know you mean well, but for questions like this about using IDEs, images are actually helpful. If they posted just the code and output, we wouldn't see the white dot on the file tab, indicating that the file is unsaved.